# Simple explanation for continuous, holomorphic and analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been studying complex analysis and I've been confused by the three terms. From my notes and from my understanding, holomorphic has something to do with a function being differentiable at a point? Continuous functions can be shown by using limits and if I'm correct, the limit as z -> a is the same as f(a) for f(z). As for analytic, I'm not quite sure. I have done some online researching however, the math jargon often confuses me so, I was wondering if anyone is able to explain continuous, holomorphic, and analytic in very simple terms? Also, how would one go about showing if a function is continuous, holomorphic or analytic given any complex function? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Different textbooks may disagree on the definition of analytic in this context, and there might be whole chapters (or more) on "showing a function is holomorphic". This question is a bit too broad to be answered in a very helpful way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function.

- $f$ is said to be **continuous** if for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ there exist an $\delta > 0$ and $z_1 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
  $$ f^{-1} \big( B_\epsilon (z_0) \big) = B_\delta (z_1), $$
  where $B_\epsilon (z_0) = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid | z - z_0 | < \epsilon \right\}$.
- $f$ is said to be **continuously differentiable** on $\mathbb{C}$ if the limit
  $$f' (z_0) = \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0}$$
  exists for all $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and as function $f': \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is also a continuous.
- $f$ is said to be **analytic** on $\mathbb{C}$ if for every $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ there exists an open ball $B_\epsilon (z_0)$ where $f$ can be approximated by a power series, i.e.,
  $$ f (z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k (z - z_0)^k.$$

By definition holomorphic means continuously differentiable.
This renaming might seem redundant for beginners in complex analysis, though holomorphic functions behave very differently from their real counterparts.
As example, compare the following three properties of holomorphic functions (that you will encounter in any introductionary course on complex analysis) to their real counterparts.

- Any real valued holomorphic function must be constant.
- A function is holomorphic if and only if it is analytic.
- Any holomorphic function that is bounded must be constant.

Also, for beginners it might seem that almost every interesting function is holomorphic, but this is far from truth.
As counterexample, can you show that
$$ x + i y \mapsto x - i y$$
is continuous but not holomorphic?

Answer (score 0):

Continuous is essentially the same as in real analysis: a function $f$ is continuous at a point $p \in \mathbb C$ if $\lim_{z \to p} f(z) = f(p)$.

Holomorphic and analytic are  the same thing in this context.
A function $f$ is holomorphic in a region $\Omega$ of the complex plane if
the derivative $f'(p) = \lim_{z \to p} \frac{f(z) - f(p)}{z-p}$ exists for all
$p \in \Omega$.